# Prove a bounded subset of a compact set is closed

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Consider R2 equipped with the Euclidean metric d2. Let A be a non-empty subset of R2, that is bounded and closed in (R2,d2). Let
S = {x^2 + y^2 : (x, y) ∈ A} ⊂ R

Question: Show that S is a closed subset of (R, | · |).

My attempt: I tried to prove by contradiction, that is, there exists an element x^2+y^2 in the closure of S but not in S. Then (x,y) is in the complement of A. Then there exists r>0 such that B((x,y),r) is in A complement. As x^2+y^2 is an accumulation point (limit point) of S, then for any ε>0, B(x^2+y^2)∩ S-{x^2+y^2} is not empty. I was stuck here and failed to define ε in terms of r

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$ is continuous so that the image under $f$ of any compact set is again compact. In $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ with usual topology a set is compact iff it is bounded and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(r_n)$ be a sequence in $S$ which converges to some point $r$. We need to show that $r \in S$. (Let us denote $||(a,b)|| := \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, and let $K := ub(A)$)

As $r_n \in S \Rightarrow \exists (x_n,y_n) \in A$ s.t. $ ||(x_n,y_n)||^2 = r_n $.
As $A$ is closed, $\exists (x,y) \in A$ s.t. $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,y)$.

In order to prove the result, it suffices to show that $||(x_n,y_n)||^2 \rightarrow ||(x,y)||^2$ given $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,y)$. This follows directly from the triangle inequality and boundedness of $A$:
\begin{align*}
||(x_n,y_n)||^2 -  ||(x,y)||^2 &\leq (||(x_n,y_n)|| -  ||(x,y)||)(||(x_n,y_n)|| +  ||(x,y)||) \\
&\leq 2K(||(x_n,y_n)|| -  ||(x,y)||) \\
&\leq 2K||(x_n,y_n) - (x,y)|| 
\end{align*}
Qed.

Comment: But we do not have square root. What we need is xn^2+yn^2-x^2-y^2 <= (xn-x)^2+(yn-y)^2

Comment: 1. Yes, I missed that. It doesn't make a difference, but I edited my answer.
2. Do check drhab's answer in the comments above. It is much more concise and general.
3. When writing math phrases, enclose them in 'dollar-sign'.

Comment: Thanks!! But I think the function from A to S may not be continuous since we did not define A. Besides, we are not allowed to use concept compact set

Comment: $A$ is given to be  a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence there is a metric defined on $A$, and that function will always be continuous.

Comment: Wait a minute. I still have two questions: 1. what it means by K:=ub(A). 2. $()$ converges to r does not implies $(,)$ converges to (x,y) for example, 4+9 = 9+4

Comment: I enclosed phrases in 'dollar-sign' but nothing changes

Comment: $K = ub(A) \Rightarrow \forall (x,y) \in A, ||(x.y)|| \leq K$.
$||(x_n,y_n)||^2 \rightarrow || (x,y) ||^2 $ implies that $ r_n \rightarrow || (x,y) ||^2 $, and as limits are unique we have $ r = || (x,y) ||^2 $. And this implies that $r \in S$.

Enclosing dollars makes a difference, here are a few codes though:
subscript : use '_' eg: a_{n} (enclose this in dollars)
superscript" use ^
Examples of some symbols:
less than equalto : \leq
.. And for more symbols just google it. This is LaTeX code (so just google stuff like Latex symbol for less than equalto etc)

Comment: Just consider a circle centered at the origin. How can we define (x,y) then?

Comment: I haven't said that $(r_n) \rightarrow r \Rightarrow (x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,y)$. This follows from the closure property of $A$. Read the second paragraph carefully.

Comment: I think I solved this problem since every sequence has a convergent subsequence. So we do not need the entire sequence, we can construct r by the subsequence. Thanks for your help!!!